# Render image on the surface with Mayavi and Python

Tags: python, 3d, mayavi

I am trying to create visualization with use of Python and Mayavi.
The purpose of that visualization is to show a trajectory and camera frustums at different stages of the path.

[image: Rended_screenshot]
The thing I struggle with is to texturize camera frustum polygons with an actual images.

I am willing to put performance considerations aside for now, and want to find a way to texture a mayavi-created surface with an image provided by numpy.

The most promising suggestions were found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107084/mayavi-texture-to-span-over-full-surface?rq=1), yet I was unable to construct a surface as I implemented them.

```
def render_image(self, frustum, timestamp):
        surf = mayavi.mlab.surf(frustum[0, :-1],
                                frustum[1, :-1],
                                frustum[2, :-1],
                                color = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
```

That's the code for surface creation, where rows of the numpy array frustum are x, y, z coordinates respectively and the last, fifth point is the tip of pyramid and hence not needed for mesh.

```
x [-8.717184671492793, -8.623419637172622, -8.363581977642212, -8.269816943322041]
y [-4.563044562134721, -4.941612408713827, -4.37100415350352, -4.749572000082626]
z [13.614485323873417, 13.703336344550703, 14.059553426925493, 14.148404447602779]
```

That is an example of function input - four 3D points representing vertices of a desired polygon.

Yet, the surf function fails on that input:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/helper_functions.py", line 679, in __call_internal__
    aspect_ratios = [(zf - zi) / (xf - xi), (zf - zi) / (yf - yi)]
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

**Note:** I was able to render images with mayavi.mlab.imshow, but I find it error-prone and onerous to specify image pose and size in terms of axis angles and scale vectors, so I'm reluctant to accept answers pointing to that direction.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would suggest that you try to reduce the problem a bit so that you have a simpler example where the problem persists. If the source of the problem still eludes you, please provide the data and the code completely so that it is easier for people to reproduce your problem. This would help with problems arising out of changes in versions or hardware.

Comment: @DebanjanBasu, Thanks. Actually, the issue is still relevant for me. I will rework the question and update.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you find a way of doing it?

Comment: @martinako Nay. But I will find time soon to try again and will update on a progress

Answer (score 1):

I got to draw textured cameras with mayavi! 
see:

[image]

Although the way I've done it is using mlab.imshow, so it maybe this is the type of answer you don't want. See this code:

```
obj=mlab.imshow(image.T)
obj.actor.orientation = np.rad2deg(camera.w_Rt_c.euler)
pp = np.array([0, 0, camera.f])[:,None]
w_pp = camera.w_Rt_c.forward(pp)
obj.actor.position = w_pp.ravel()
obj.actor.scale = [0.8, 0.8, 0.8]
```

image is a (n,m) numpy array, for some reason imshow would show the image 90 degrees rotated, that's why I transpose it.

obj.actor.orientation expects a yaw, pitch, roll angles is degrees. The rotation of the image is the product of individual rotation matrices Rx(yaw)*Ry(pitch)*Rz(roll). In the code I use the camera to world euler angles of my camera class (can't share that code at the moment).

The position of the image is set to the 3d position where the principal point of my camera would be transformed to world coordinates.

Why the scale factor is 0.8 is a mystery, if I leave it to 1 the image plane appear larger than the frustum???

I encapsulate the above in a class that expects a camera and an image and draws the frustum and the image at the position and orientation of the given camera.

Comment: Even though the imshow approach is less favorable, I will use your example and tinker a bit more with it. Upon receiving the satisfying results, I will accept.