# How to edit points data in vtk file

Tags: python-3.x, vtk, mayavi

I am trying to project some points of mesh using some function. I have access the point and cell data from polydata. From that I get projected point. Now I want to replace those points with projected points. Is there any way to update points in mayavi or vtk?

To get polydata from .ply file

```
from plyfile import PlyData,PlyElement
import numpy as np 
import time
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.api import tvtk

plydata = PlyData.read(ply_file)
points = plydata.elements[0].data

# Get X,Y,Z coordinates from .ply file
x,y,z = [],[],[]                                                                                                                                                                                    

for i in points: 
    x.append(i[0]) 
    y.append(i[1]) 
    z.append(i[2]) 

s = [0.1]*len(x)

mesh = mlab.pipeline.delaunay2d(pts)
surf = mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh,color=(1,1,1))

actor = surf.actor.actors[0]
polydata = tvtk.to_vtk(actor.mapper.input)
```

projecting points:

```
for i in range(polydata.GetNumberOfCells()):
    pts = polydata.GetCell(i).GetPoints()    
    np_pts = np.array([pts.GetPoint(i) for i in range(pts.GetNumberOfPoints())])
    projected_point1,projected_point2,projected_point3 = project_points(point1,point2,point3)
```

Now for saving I tried following line in above for loop:

```
polydata_return.GetCell(i).GetPoints() = np.array([projected_point1,projected_point2,projected_point3])
```

but got error as follows:
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Is there any way to replace/edit present points with projected points. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**
To generate mesh :

```
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.api import tvtk
import numpy as np
from plyfile import PlyData,PlyElement

x = [random.randint(0,250) for i in range(250)]
y = [random.randint(0,250) for i in range(250)]
z = [random.randint(0,5) for i in range(250)]
s = [0.1]*len(x)

pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z,s)
mesh = mlab.pipeline.delaunay2d(pts)
surf = mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh,color=(1,1,1))
```

After generating above mesh I want to map a texture to mesh using following image and then I have to flattened the mesh using some transformation, so mesh will get flattened along with a texture. I doing this for dewrapping image to remove distortion in image.
[texture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHyY9.jpg)

For projecting image I use following code:

```
image_file = texture_image_path
if image_file.split('.')[-1] == 'png':
    img = tvtk.PNGReader()
elif image_file.split('.')[-1] == 'jpg':
    img = tvtk.JPEGReader()

img.file_name=image_file
texture = tvtk.Texture(input_connection=img.output_port, interpolate=0)

surf.actor.enable_texture = True  
surf.actor.tcoord_generator_mode = 'plane'  
surf.actor.actor.texture = texture
mlab.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840638/update-mayavi-plot-in-loop

Comment: `# Connect them
src.mlab_source.dataset.lines = connections
src.update()` in https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_plotting_many_lines.html

Comment: https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_animating.html

Comment: Thanks @Joe. src.mlab_source, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi @Joe I am able to make changes using mlab_souce. But it is not working if we use it after mapping texture to mesh. I use **surf.mlab_source.points** to update the points.

Comment: could you add a small, complete working example to show what you mean. Please add random datapoints instead of showing where you load them from.

Comment: @Joe I have updated question with sample code and what I actually want to achieve.

Comment: Does this fit your case? https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/211

Comment: Ok, now I see the texture mapped onto the random surface. Now, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Joe I managed to map a texture to mesh. Now I want to  flattened the mesh using some transformation, so mesh will get flattened along with a texture.But I am not able to flattened the mesh after mapping texture. I am doing this for dewrapping image to remove distortion in image.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started, you just have to use the correct data at the correct position. There are several attributes to `mesh.mlab_source`.
I added some in the comments.

```
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.api import tvtk
import numpy as np
#from plyfile import PlyData,PlyElement
import random

x = [random.randint(0,250) for i in range(250)]
y = [random.randint(0,250) for i in range(250)]
z = [random.randint(0,5) for i in range(250)]
s = [0.1]*len(x)

pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z,s)
mesh = mlab.pipeline.delaunay2d(pts)
surf = mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh,color=(1,1,1))

#After generating above mesh I want to map a texture to mesh using following image and then I have to flattened the mesh using some transformation, so mesh will get flattened along with a texture. I doing this for dewrapping image to remove distortion in image. texture image

#For projecting image I use following code:

image_file = 'texture.jpg'
if image_file.split('.')[-1] == 'png':
    img = tvtk.PNGReader()
elif image_file.split('.')[-1] == 'jpg':
    img = tvtk.JPEGReader()


img.file_name=image_file
texture = tvtk.Texture(input_connection=img.output_port, interpolate=1)
#texture = tvtk.Texture(interpolate=1)
#texture.input = img

surf.actor.enable_texture = True  
surf.actor.tcoord_generator_mode = 'plane'  
surf.actor.actor.texture = texture

#src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_scatter(x, y, z, s)
#src.mlab_source.dataset.lines = connections src.update(
#src.mlab_source.reset()

@mlab.animate
def anim():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)

        #plt.mlab_source.set(x=x, y=y, z=z)
        print(surf.mlab_source.dataset)
        x = [random.randint(0,250) for i in range(250)]
        y = [random.randint(0,250) for i in range(250)]
        z = [random.randint(0,5) for i in range(250)]
        s = [0.1]*len(x)

        pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z,s)
        mesh = mlab.pipeline.delaunay2d(pts)


        surf.mlab_source.x = mesh.mlab_source.x
        surf.mlab_source.y = mesh.mlab_source.y
        surf.mlab_source.z = mesh.mlab_source.z


        #s.mlab_source.scalars = np.asarray(x*0.1*(i+1), 'd')
        yield

anim()

mlab.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. New problem I am facing is , when I map image as a texture to a mesh, alignment of image and mesh is mismatch. Image is getting larger than mesh. Is there any setting to align mesh with texture image.

Comment: https://discourse.vtk.org/t/python-vtk-can-we-get-the-mesh-rendered-from-the-colorized-point-cloud/200

Comment: This related to the plane mapping. Do you know how texture mapping works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107084/mayavi-texture-to-span-over-full-surface

Comment: Thank you. I will check the shared links. I just know that texture mapping is uses one-2-one type mapping.